# Is it possible reverse the scroll position in a scrollview so it scrolls from the bottom up?

Tags: famo.us

Is it possible reverse the scroll position in a scrollview so it scrolls from the bottom up?
It would be helpful to do this because it would allow me to lay the scrollview flat and stand the surfaces up and still have the first surfaces at the front.It's a bit hard to explain so I have this image [image] Basically I am trying to scroll through these surfaces like a filing system. Is there perhaps a better way to simulate this?